# java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

My application has two entity Product and Category. When add product , user choose the category that product belong to. But when save the product to data base i meet the error

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation

the content of entity is 
Category.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="category")
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name="category_name")
private String categoryName;

@Column(name="description")
private String description;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Product> products;

//getter and setter method
}
```

Product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(name="name")
@NotNull
@NotEmpty
private String name;

@Column(name="description")
private String description;

@Column(name="manufacture")
private String manufacture;

@Column(name="price")
private long price;

@Column(name="image_name")
private String imageName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
Category category;

//getter and setter method
}
```

ProductDAO.java

```
@Repository("ProductDAO")
@Transactional
public class ProductDAO {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

public void create(Product product) {
    entityManager.merge(product.getCategory());
    entityManager.persist(product);
}
//other method
}
```

my jsp file

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="product" action="add.html" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Productname <form:input path="name"/>
                <form:errors path="name" class ="error"/><br>
    description    <form:input   path="description"/><br>
    price    <form:input   path="price"/><br>
    manufacture <form:input path="manufacture"/><br>
    Category
    <form:select path="category">
    <form:options items="${categories}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="categoryName" />
    </form:select>
    <form:errors path="category" class ="error"/><br>
    <br/>
    Product image<input type="file" name="file" />
    <form:errors path="imageName" class ="error"/><br>
    <input type="submit" class="register" value="Save">
</form:form>
```

my Converter

```
public class CategoryConverter implements Converter<String, Category>{

    @Autowired
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    public Category convert(String id) {
        return categoryService.findById(Long.valueOf(id));
    }
}
```

thank for any help

Comment: I think you have to `persists` the category first and then the product. Or add `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to the `@oneToMany` annotation.

Comment: @Jen: the category is already in database. when i add the cascade=CascadeType.ALL, I meet another broblem. When i added new product, a new catagory is added, too

Comment: Have you tried to add `CascadeType.ALL´` and remove `entityManager.merge(product.getCategory());`

Comment: Yes, I tried. Add new product successfull but i check the database, I see a new category is added ,too . I post my jsp file and converter as above

Comment: Have you called `category.setProduct(product)` before you call persists? Can you show the code wich add the objects before the `create` method is called?

Comment: @DenisLawrin remide you again: if the category object of your product is existing in database, you should LOAD YOUR CATEGORY OBJECT FIRST AND SET IT TO YOUR PRODUCT! then, no any duplicated category will be saved!

Comment: Thank Jens and  Laurence Geng. I fixed the bug . I post create funtion bellow. I also chage the FetchType.LAZY of Category to EAGER

Comment: "cascade = CascadeType.ALL" will give a type mismatch error because cascade expects an array of values. It should be "cascade = [CascadeType.ALL]"

Answer (score 3):

please add (cascade=CascadeType.ALL) into category field mapping of Product

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
Category category;
```

and remove this line in ProductDAO:

```
entityManager.merge(product.getCategory());
```

NOTE: if your product's category is an existing one, you should load it first then set it to your product, this is normal flow. Do not new duplicated Category object.

Comment: when i add the cascade=CascadeType.ALL, I meet another broblem. When i added new product, a new catagory is added, too.

Comment: @DenisLawrin remove line: entityManager.merge(product.getCategory());

Comment: Yes, I tried. Add new product successfull but i check the database, I see a new category is added ,too . I post my jsp file and converter as above

Answer (score 2):

This my fixed code

```
@Transactional
public void create(Product product) {
    Category category=categoryDAO.findById(product.getCategory().getId());
    category.getProducts().add(product);
    categoryDAO.edit(category);
    product.setCategory(category);
    this.productDAO.create(product);
}
```