# Hibernate TransientPropertyValueException while persisting many-to-one relationship having entityid as 0

Tags: hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

I am getting a strange exception while persisting an **Order** object
having a many to one relationship with **deliveryMode**.

Following is the mapping defined in the **Order** object.

```
@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumn(name = "DELIVERY_MODE_ID")   
private DeliveryMode deliveryMode;
```

The **delivery modes already exist in database**,
hence there is no need of specifying cascade.

Following is the bidirectional mapping in the DeliveryMode class :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "deliveryMode")
private List<Order> orders;
```

I am setting the DeliveryMode in the Order object and saving the Order using JPA entity Manager as:

```
Order order = new Order();
DeliveryMode deliveryMode = new DeliveryMode();
deliveryMode.setDeliveryModeId(0);
order.setDeliveryMode(deliveryMode);
entityManager.persist(order);
```

Above code is giving following exception :

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: 
object references an unsaved transient instance for given deliveryMode.
```

The entry with deliveryModeId = 0 already exists in database.
When I am trying to save an entry with deliveryModeId other than 0
above snippet works fine.

Thanks :)

Comment: Probably primary key as 0 is fishy to hibernate.

Comment: can you show the java class for delivery mode?

Comment: I have updated the delivery mode mapping.

Comment: have you tried using entityManager.merge(order) ?

Comment: go through the solution of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439927/java-lang-illegalstateexception-org-hibernate-transientpropertyvalueexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the solution. I was using primitive short for Id. 
**Converting it to wrapper** solved the problem. 
It seems that hibernate is not accepting 0 as ID in case a primitive datatype is used.
Thanks all :)

When using primitive types, the primary key id will be set to 0 by default, If 0 is the value of an actual id column in the corresponding table of the entity, hibernate gets confused.

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
Order order = new Order();
DeliveryMode deliveryMode = new DeliveryMode();
deliveryMode.setDeliveryModeId(0);
order.setDeliveryMode(deliveryMode);
entityManager.persist(order);
```

You have created a new `Order` object and a new `DeliveryMode` object and then assigning the `DeliveryMode` to your `Order` object. Then you are passing the `Order` object to hibernate and asking it to save it (or persist it).

Now hibernate takes the object it got from persist method which is `Order` object and places it in its session cache (first level cache). Now while saving this `Order` it observes that the parent `Order` object has a child `DeliveryMode` object. So it will check in its session (first level cache) and see if it has any `DeliveryMode` object with `id` as `0` which you have set in your code. Then it finds that there is no such object for `DeliveryMode` with `id` as `0` so it throws an exception saying you have to save the `DeliveryMode` object before saving `Order` object. That is what the exception says:

```
org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: 
object references an unsaved transient instance for given deliveryMode.
```

So to fix this issue you need to get the `DeliveryMode` object from database for the required `id` which is `0`. Once you get the object the object will be in hibernate's session cache. Now assign this `DeliveryMode` object to your `Order` object and then save your `Order` object.

As suggested by Ahishs in his comments, check this link on how you can do this : [java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439927/java-lang-illegalstateexception-org-hibernate-transientpropertyvalueexception)

Comment: Hi Chaitanya I got the DeliveryMode object from hibernate and tried saving the Order. But still the issue persists, and again this is happening only when deliveryModeId is 0.

Comment: @RishabhRawal, can you post the exact code you have tried and also add the complete stacktrace of exception to your question instead of one liner error message.